# Server-Sent Evenets: Change time interval

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I was looking at `Server-Sent Events`, since the client is on **shared hosting** and I can't use websockets.

I have tested an [W3School's example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) and it is working beautifuly.My code looks like this:
**Index.php (relevant section):**

```
<script>
    var source=new EventSource("data.php");
    source.onmessage=function(event)
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
</script>
```

**Data.php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Now, the output i get looks like this:

```
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:25 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:28 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:31 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:34 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:37 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:40 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:43 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:46 +0200
The server time is: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 13:31:49 +0200
```

I have noticed, that `time-interval` here is **3 seconds.**
My question is: **How can I change this time interval?** 
In the `data.php` I intend to have a code that sends a request and gets back a response, but the number of requests is limited, so I need to make that interval bigger.

Is this even a good way of solving a problem, or should I use `polling`?

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'm really not sure how to describe the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events This link may be helpful. Also, [w3schools is (somehow) deprecated here](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like this, but the fact is - you are not using it correctly.

The PHP script shouldn't terminate - you should use a loop. With this loop, you can also control the interval (the easiest way would be to `sleep($seconds)`).

```
while(true) {
   $time = date('r');
   echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
   flush();
   sleep(3);   // interval: 3 seconds
}
```

The reason your script seems to work is that the browser always tries to reestablish a connection, because the event-stream terminated (considered an error by the browser). However, this isn't different than just polling the server every X seconds, eliminating the advantage of event streams.

Also, Apache and PHP are not recommended to use for event-streams - Apache isn't designed for connections that remain open indefinitely (This may no longer be true - haven't kept up to date), and many hosters restrict the execution time for PHP scripts. Either use a different web server, or use polling, to avoid potential problems.

Comment: So, if I use SSes correctly, the request for data.phh is sent only once, right and its kept open?

Comment: indeed. that's the main benefit over polling - all the overhead of establishing a new connection doesn't apply. plus, the ability to send new events as soon as they are available, without the need for a fixed interval.

Comment: Maybe I should go and read the SSE spec, but how do you end the events?

Comment: @boisvert, so does html5rocks.com. kinda sad, if you think about it. Also, you can prevent the client from reestablishing a connection and just terminate the script. need to google the method name tough.

Comment: @boisvert: you end them with \n\n

Answer (score 0):

You can use **echo data:** less than 3 sec with a **cicle**

```
  <?php
  header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
  header( 'Content-Type: text/event-stream' );
  header( 'X-Accel-Buffering: no' ); 

  ob_implicit_flush( true );
  ob_end_flush();
  for ( $i = 0; $i < 30; $i++ ) {
    $data = "data: $i";
    echo $data . "\n\n";
    if(ob_get_level()>0){ob_flush();}
    flush();
    usleep(500000);
  }
  echo "data: Done!\n\n";
```

or unlimited

```
  while (true) {
  echo "data: test\n\n";
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  usleep(500000);
  }
```